# Eclipse shows error (unable to resolve target)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resolve

I got a project and imported it in Eclipse (it is an android project).
The project works on other computers, but unfortunately not on mine.
The error which comes up is in the console of eclipse when i import the project:
"Unable to resolve target 'android-8'"

Furthermore do i get multiple errors in on of the .java-files in the src folder of the project.

3 of them are showing "String cannot be resolved to type":

Here the code (It is for a music player the timer /showing of the seconds):

```
    /**
 * Function to convert milliseconds time to
 * Timer Format
 * Hours:Minutes:Seconds
 * */
public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";
```

I hope you can help me!

Thank you so much in advance!

If you have any questions please let me know.

Thanks guys.

Cheers

Comment: Did you use `File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into workspace` or `File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace`? Make sure that you use the first alternative.

Comment: try to clean the project, else,right click on the project,build path, then change the target api level to the one that is installed, or right click the project, select properties and fix project properties, also check the manifest file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick respond. I first tried Simons alternative, so i used Existing Android Code into workspace, the error i get then is: "[2013-10-22 22:39:22 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for D:\ANDROID\android_dev_environment\workspace\AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer\AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file."

If i clean the project nothing else changes... however my manifest file shows: 'Multiple annotations found at this line'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have something set with a build target of API 8. Perhaps a subproject or library?

If that's intended then it sounds like you need to download Android 2.2 (API 8) through your Android SDK manager.

Comment: i did the update on 2.2 restarted eclipse, tried to import the project (because i couldnt open the already imported one), and now it says: Invalid porject description and it doesnt open. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be having **project.properties** file open that and change the **android-8** to whatever android version you have. After changing this goto Window->Preferences->Android. You'll be having **target name & api level**. select any one of them & specify it in **project.properties** file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that quick respond. my project.properties says "# Project target.
target=android-16"

And the Android 4.1.2 has an API lvl of 16.

Comment: Do you have android-16 api level. Please check in Window->Preferences->Android.

Comment: Yes i do. Just to show you, not that i misunderstand something, here is a screenshot: http://s11.postimg.org/x5l4axatf/screen_api.png

Comment: What does the error you have in **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Comment: it says:   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.androidhive.musicplayer"></manifest>

Comment: Try to Clean & build then run your program, if this didn't work, can you show me your AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, Properties -> Android -> Select the build target -> Apply -> OK

Comment: Thank you, i checked it with Android 4.1.2 and 4.3, nothing changes though. The same errors occur.